# Override Material Table Export Button Design React js

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am new in react js I am using material UI. I have used Material Table to display server side data. I want to change the Export button design. Is there any way to override the export button design or use material table export function with custom button?[image: Default export button]

`<MaterialTable
tableRef={tableRefEmp}
title={"Employee"}

```
                columns={[
                  {title: "Name", field: 'first_name', render: (rowData) => 
                    !!rowData && rowData.first_name !== undefined ? (<EmployeePopUpLink rowData={rowData} />) : ('') 
                  },
                  {title: 'Company', field: 'company',  render: (rowData) =>
                  !!rowData && rowData.company !== undefined  && rowData.company !== null ? (
                    <CompanyPopUpLink rowData={rowData} />
                  ) : (
                    ''
                  ) },
                  {title: 'Title', field: 'title' }, 
                  {title: 'Get Data', field: 'title', render: (rowData) => {
                    return !!rowData && <LoopAddToCartSplitBtn employee={ rowData } />
                  }}, 
              ]}
                data={tableData}   
                localization={{
                    body: {
                        emptyDataSourceMessage: tableMsg,
                    },
                }}
                options={{
                    search: false,
                    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#192d3e', color: '#fff'},
                    pageSize: 10,
                    pageSizeOptions: [10, 25, 50, 100],
                    exportButton: true,
                    sorting: false,
                    selection: true,
                    rowStyle: rowData => {

                       if(rowData.company_id+"_"+rowData.employee_id === openedCompanyId){
                         return {backgroundColor: "rgb(248 248 248)"};
                       }else if(rowData.employee_id === openedEmployeeId){
                         return {backgroundColor: "rgb(248 248 248)"};
                       }

                    }
                }}
                components={{
                  Toolbar: props =>{
                      // This will let you use your own Title while keeping the search
                      const propsCopy = { ...props };
                      console.log(propsCopy);
                      // Hide default title
                      propsCopy.showTitle = false;
                      return (<div className="w-full">
                         <Grid container direction="row">
                          <Grid item xs={12} md={2}>
                            <div className="flex items-center p-8 md:p-16">
                              <h2>Employee</h2>
                            </div>
                          </Grid>
                          <Grid item xs={12} md={10}>
                            <div className={"grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-4 grid grid-rows-1 gap-4 pl-8 md:pl-0"}>
                                
                                <div className="flex items-center"> <AddToDripBinButton /></div>
                                <div className="flex items-center"><AddToCartSplitButton /></div>
                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                  <Button variant="contained" onClick={props.defaultExportCsv } color="primary" size="small">Save This Search</Button>
                                </div> 
                                <div> 
                                  <MTableToolbar {...propsCopy} />
                                </div>                                                                  
                            </div>
                          </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                      </div>);
                 }
                }}
            />`
```

Comment: Show the source from material UI

Comment: I have found a solution

`const tableIcons = {
    Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <MatDownloadSplitButton className="p-0" {...props} ref={ref} />)
  };`

And added a prop in `<MaterialTable icons={tableIcons} />` tag